# PHP5.4 Unable to load dynamic library gd.so undefined symbol: gdGetC

Tags: 12.04, php

I installed PHP5.4 from PPA `ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable` in my Ubuntu 12.04.2.

Then all of my image processing scripts got broken. Turns out the `php5-gd` library isn't loaded.

```
$ php -a
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/gd.so: undefined symbol: gdGetC in Unknown on line 0
Interactive mode enabled
```

Here's some package installed in my machine related to GD (hope might help, let me know if you need to know details of other packages):

```
ii  libgd2-xpm                                    2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6ubuntu2                GD Graphics Library version 2
ii  libgd2-xpm:i386                               2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6ubuntu2                GD Graphics Library version 2
ii  libgd3                                        2.1.0-2~precise+1                       GD Graphics Library
ii  php5-gd                                       5.4.17-4+debphp.org~precise+1           GD module for php5
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I will look at this problem.  It's not a real question though – it's a bugreport and I just cannot sieve through all askubuntu.com questions, so I would point you to debphp.org, where you will find a debphp-user (and debphp-announce) mailing list just suited for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real culprit is the fact that PHP 5.4 GD extension is not compatible with libgd (>= 2.1.0).  Since the gd.so is an dynamic extension it's not possible to detect the missing symbols at compile time.

Anyway the php5-oldstable has been updated:

- libgd 2.1.x has been removed
- new php5 has been updated with forced dependency on libgd 2.0.x

E.g. this bug has been fixed in php5 5.4.17-5+debphp.org~+1 (some dists are still building at the time of writing this answer).

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response. it works now. should there be another bug, i will report it right away in the link you gave above. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install php5-gd` worked for me after I had to switch from stable to old-stable due to an older apache.